# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to call an api and I get the error "Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 500". I dunno how did I get the error.I put the api call in componentDidMount. I am not sure whether the error comes from the redux implementation or from how I called the api.

This is how I called the api. After a successful login, I put the username as a token and use it to call another api.

```js
 state={
    username: '',
    semcode: [
        {}
    ]
}

componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('Login_token').then((token) => {
        console.log('this is coursescreen',token);
        let Login_token = token;
        this.setState({ username: Login_token });

    });   

}

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getSemcode(this.state.username);  
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('xx',nextProps);
    if (nextProps.semCode != undefined) {
        this.setState({ semcode: nextProps.semCode });

    }
}
```

This is how I wrote my action file:

```js
export const getSemcode = (username) => async dispatch => {

    let param = {
        nomatrik: username,
    }   

    console.log(`${helper.ROOT_URL}/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem`)
    let code_res = await 
    axios.post(`${helper.ROOT_URL}/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem`, param)
    console.log(code_res.data);    
    if (code_res.data.length > 0) {
        const { code } = code_res.data;          
        dispatch({ type: SEMCODE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: { semCode: code }});
    }

}
```

This is how I wrote my reducer:

```js
import { SEMCODE_FETCH_SUCCESS} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE={
semCode:[],
}
export default function (state=INITIAL_STATE, action){
switch(action.type){
    case SEMCODE_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
}
}
```

Can anyone help me pleaseeeeee

**Error Message**

> Error received from axios.post: {"config":{"transformRequest":
>   {},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-
>   TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":
>   {"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-
>   Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},
>   "method":"post","nomatrik":"BB16160907",
>   "url":"https://smp.ums.edu.my/api/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem","data":"
>   {\"Accept\":\"application/json\",\"Content-
>   Type\":\"application/json\"}"},"request":
>   {"UNSENT":0,"OPENED":1,"HEADERS_RECEIVED":2,"LOADING":3,"DONE":4,
>   "readyState":4,"status":500,"timeout":0,"withCredentials":true,"upload":
>   {},"_aborted":false,"_hasError":false,"_method":"POST","_response":"
>   {\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}",
>   "_url":"https://smp.ums.edu.my/api/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem",
>   "_timedOut":false,"_trackingName":"unknown",
>   "_incrementalEvents":false,"responseHeaders":{"Date":"Sat, 30 Dec 2017
>   03:58:25
>   GMT","Content-Length":"36","X-Powered-By":"ARR/3.0","X-AspNet-
>   Version":"4.0.30319","Expires":"-1","Content-Type":"application/json; 
>   charset=utf-8","Server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","Pragma":"no-cache","Cache-
>   Control":"no-cache"},"_requestId":null,"_headers":
>   {"accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","content-
>   type":"application/json;charset=utf-
>   8"},"_responseType":"","_sent":true,"_lowerCaseResponseHeaders":{"date":"Sat,
>   30 Dec 2017 03:58:25
>   GMT","content-length":"36","x-powered-by":"ARR/3.0","x-
>   aspnet-version":"4.0.30319","expires":"-1","content-type":"application/json;  charset=utf-8","server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","pragma":"no-cache","cache-
>   control":"no-cache"},"_subscriptions":[],"responseURL":
>   "https://smp.ums.edu.my/api/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem"},"response":{"data":
>   {"Message":"An error has
>   occurred."},"status":500,"headers":{"date":"Sat, 30  Dec 2017 03:58:25
>   GMT","content-length":"36","x-powered-by":"ARR/3.0","x-
>   aspnet-version":"4.0.30319","expires":"-1","content-type":"application/json;  charset=utf-8","server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","pragma":"no-cache","cache-
>   control":"no-cache"},"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":
>   {},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-
>   TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, 
>   text/plain,
>   */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"method": "post","nomatrik":"BB16160907",
>   "url":"https://smp.ums.edu.my/api/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem","data":"
>   {\"Accept\":\"application/json\",\"Content-
>   Type\":\"application/json\"}"},"request":
>   {"UNSENT":0,"OPENED":1,"HEADERS_RECEIVED":2,"LOADING":3,"DONE":4,
>   "readyState":4,"status":500,"timeout":0,"withCredentials":true,"upload":
>   {},"_aborted":false,"_hasError":false,"_method":"POST","_response":"
>   {\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}",
>   "_url":"https://smp.ums.edu.my/api/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem",
>   "_timedOut":false,"_trackingName":"unknown","_incrementalEvents":false, "responseHeaders":{"Date":"Sat, 30 Dec 2017 03:58:25 GMT","Content-
>   Length":"36","X-Powered-By":"ARR/3.0","X-AspNet-
>   Version":"4.0.30319","Expires":"-1","Content-Type":"application/json; 
>   charset=utf-8","Server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","Pragma":"no-cache","Cache-
>   Control":"no-cache"},"_requestId":null,"_headers":
>   {"accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","content-
>   type":"application/json;charset=utf-
>   8"},"_responseType":"","_sent":true,"_lowerCaseResponseHeaders":{"date":"Sat,
>   30 Dec 2017 03:58:25
>   GMT","content-length":"36","x-powered-by":"ARR/3.0","x-
>   aspnet-version":"4.0.30319","expires":"-1","content-type":"application/json;  charset=utf-8","server":"Microsoft-IIS/10.0","pragma":"no-cache","cache-
>   control":"no-cache"},"_subscriptions":
>   [],"responseURL":"https://smp.ums.edu.my/api/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem"}}}

Login action:

```js
export const attemptLogin = (username, password) => async dispatch => {

let param = {
    txtNomatrik: username,
    txtPwd: password,
    public_key: helper.PUBLIC_KEY,
    secret_key: helper.SECRET_KEY

}

console.log(`${helper.ROOT_API_URL}/v1/basic/ad/std/login`)
let login_res = await 
axios.post(`${helper.ROOT_API_URL}/v1/basic/ad/std/login`, param)

console.log(login_res.data);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('jwtToken',login_res.data.token);
if (login_res.data.status == 'Successful login') {
    const { login } = login_res.data;    
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS});   
}
}
```

Comment: Hey gdphy may I suggest you download postman. It is a really neat app that lets you test your API calls in a nice GUI. It will show you the response and help you debug your applications. https://www.getpostman.com/ Good luck!

Comment: The api is working fine in postman. I tried debugging the error and I got error like below which I dunno how to solve it

Comment: Cool I would be happy to help you. Tell me a few things. 1. What API are you using. 2. Are you sure your passing any token necessary to the api end point? 3. Is there any docs for the API you can show me? It looks like your passing a token to the variable username and setting it as a param. Then making the axios POST request. I have had problems like this before, 100 percent of the time it is the API expects you to format your query a certain way and I was doing it a tiny bit wrong. It could be as simple as making sure you set a header, Content-Type: application/json. Try and send me the info.

Comment: omg I am such a fool, now I realised sth. I forgot to include the jwt token. May I know how to include the jwt token in header when making axios request?. I seriously dunno how to o it. I did store the jwt token in asyncstorage in my login action but then  dunno how to proceed.

Comment: No problem. I was thinking it was something like this. I just added an answer for you. Please accept my answer. I am going to add a few more examples real quick too. The other problem you might face is that sometimes you have to form the request in a special way based on the api end point you are hitting. usually it will show you an example. So if you can give me a link to the api I can look. Otherwise try and use the examples in my answer below.

Comment: OK buddy let me know if my answer makes sense or if you have anymore questions. If it helps you please make it is the answer.

Comment: I'm still struggling with how to write the function to get the api. Anyway this is the link to the api [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OpYcilyUk9KSwPunfk2WYl2oZpu1R7JsnKzxTFSCOQI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: When I hit the login part I guess this response, {
    "login": {},
    "status": null,
    "ipaddr": "IP",
    "token": null
}  This is how I am supposed to get a token right?

Comment: That's the response if you failed to log in. [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OpYcilyUk9KSwPunfk2WYl2oZpu1R7JsnKzxTFSCOQI/edit?usp=sharing) I updated the api doc with valid credentials. Sorry, I forgot about that. So after successful login, what I want to pass in the header is the token from the response since it is needed for the next request

Comment: Yes I do not have all the data though. You are missing things in the doc. I am trying to chat with you in the doc but you are not responding. message me back in the doc. This is not a hard task if we can communicate we can knock this out quick.

Comment: btw, I tried saving the token in the asyncstorage and in my semcode action i included the jwtToken I retrieved from the asyncstorage. Yet the I received "Authorization":"Bearer undefined" error

Comment: Yes you do not need to use barer. You will use AntiTemperSignature: token

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

Your request is failing because you are not adding the JWT token to the headers.

**Solution**

Using Axios and with your code this should work. Evidently our big problem here was that you have to pass `data` even though it is empty. If we do not pass `data` it fails with `error 500`.

```js
export const getSemcode = (username) => async dispatch => {

  let jwtToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwtToken').then((data) => {
        console.log('this is semcode',data);
    });   


    let config = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'url/to/sem',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          AntiTemperSignature: jwtToken,
          UserID: '123456',
        },
        data: '',
      json: true
    };

  try {
    return axios(config)
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(response);
       if (response.data.length > 0) {
           const { code } = response.data;
           dispatch({ type: SEMCODE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: { semCode: code } });
       }
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking in the wrong place.

An error code 500 is returned by the remote server when it can't handle the request.  In this case, I suspect that the POST to `${helper.ROOT_URL}/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem` is failing.  The axios library is a promise based library.  Wrap the call in a try-catch block like this:

```js
try {
  console.log(`${helper.ROOT_URL}/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem`)
  let code_res = await 
  axios.post(`${helper.ROOT_URL}/result/GetListOfKodSesiSem`, param)
  console.log(code_res.data);    
  if (code_res.data.length > 0) {
    const { code } = code_res.data;          
    dispatch({ type: SEMCODE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: { semCode: code }});
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(`Error received from axios.post: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
}
```

This will at least give you a view in your debug console on what is happening.  You can then coordinate that call with any debug logs from the backend to figure out what the error really is.

Your root cause, however, is that the remote server is returning a Server Error (HTTP code 500) to your client.